# hudson unset user variable

Tags: hudson

I am using hudson, but it does not set variables like HOME and USER which are 
used my bash scripts. Those variables are correct on other server that runs debian, and on open suse are not set.

I see that on open suse the server is started by  /sbin/startproc.

I could go for built parametrization: This build is parameterized.

But then I have to approve the parameters every time.

Can you point me a workaround or correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you go into slave configuration, there is an option to set Environment Variables

2) You could set them as parameters to your build

Option 1 I am assuming OpenSuse is a slave. If the two variables are not job dependent (it seems they are not), you should use option 1. If they are job dependent, use option 2.

"I see that on open suse the server is started by /sbin/startproc" what server are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks, exactly I figure that out yestarday. This option should be more visible. Regarding that server I meant hudson itself.

Comment: Awesome. Good luck with that!